# How to a parameter from my URL to Modal and Controller in Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All, i am facing an issue with passing a parameter into my Modal to sent the value of a field. I am able to pass and lookup the value via params if i go to new page where i can find the value from the URL params. But i am trying to use the same logic but in a modal and i can't seem to get it to work.

_my comments partial has the following

```html
<% Reply.all.each do |reply|%>
<% if reply.parent_id == comment.id%>
    <p class="feed-s-connection-update-item__headline Sans-1px-black-55%">
        <%=  image_tag(User.find(reply.user_id).avatar,:size => "20x20",class: "image-responsive") %>
            <%=reply.body %>
    </p>
    <%end%>
        <%end%>

            <% from_reply_form ||= nil %>
                <% unless from_reply_form %>
                    <p>
                        <%= link_to 'reply', new_reply_path( :id => comment.id) %>
                    </p>
                    <%= link_to 'Add release', new_reply_path(@reply,:id => comment.id), {:remote => true,  ':id' => 'comment.id','data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#replyModal'}  %>

                        <% end %>
                            <div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                            </div>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                            <%end%>
```

I am trying this out using this link:

```
 <%= link_to 'Add release', new_reply_path(@reply,:id => comment.id), {:remote => true,  ':id' => 'comment.id','data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#replyModal'}  %>
```

If i use i am taking to the new page and will have the params in the url which works fine

```
url: https://hidemyurldevel/replies/new?id=72

<%= link_to 'reply', new_reply_path( :id => comment.id) %></p>
```

I am able to see the same URL when i try the other URL where remote is true, but i am not able to see the PARENT_ID populated.

Replies_controller  - know this part i need to remove the respond but i have it break here so i can see whats returning

```
  def create
    @reply = Reply.new(reply_params)
    if @reply.save
     flash[:notice] = "thanks for reply"
     respond_to do |format|
     format.js
    redirect_to :back
   end  
   end 
   end 


    def new
      @reply = Reply.new
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
      @userid = current_user.id
    end
```

Here is the Modal i call 
for some reason the value is not populated into the Modal

```html
   <%= form_for(@reply) do |f| %>

    <div id="replyModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-  hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-  hidden="true">×</button>
            Post A Reply
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form center-block">
            <div class="form-group">
               Post <%= f.text_area :body, class:"form-control input-lg" %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value =>@userid  %>  
                 <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value =>@comment.id %>
            </div>
             <div class="field">


           </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">reply</button>
            <ul class="pull-left list-inline"><li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i></a></li><li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i></a></li><li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></a></li></ul>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm"%>
  </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <%end%>
```

I can't seem to be able to use the parent_id from the URL and pass it into the

This works fine if you go to the new page but not when i try passing it into the URL to the controller. Please help!

Comment: how do i capture the parent_id - which is the comment_id i am capturing from the calling view... and pass that back to controller which will use it as parent_id ..... it is paramertize as @comment.id In the hidden field... comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

Comment: <%= link_to 'Add release', new_reply_path(@reply,:id => comment.id), {:remote => true,  ':id' => 'comment.id','data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#replyModal'}  %>

Answer (score 0):

So guys i solve my problem... I am not sure if this is the right way to go, but i wasn't setting the comment parameters and it was Nill to begin with.... i just initialize the comment and set it to the instance of the comments and that works..

Excerpt
i am iterating the comment

then in my reply section where i add a comment field next to each comment i am able to pass the value in the URL

```
 <%@comment = comment%>
 <%= link_to 'Add release',    new_reply_path(:@comment => comment), {:remote => true,  :id => comment.id,'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#replyModal'}  %>
```